# Relating phase transition with symmetry-breaking according to Landau Theory

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking, ads-cft

I am trying to reproduce the results from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.09456) where they find out the expression for the Landau functional to be

$$\psi(x,t,p)=\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{x}+6x+px^3-4tx^2)$$

Now we plot Landau functional v/s the order parameter($x$) at $t=t_2$ where $t_2=\sqrt{\frac{p(3-\sqrt{p})}{2}}$ for different values of $p$

[image: figure]

Now it is a second order phase transition. According to Landau theory, every phase transition is related to a symmetry breaking. Which symmetry is being broken here, for this system of AdS black holes?